# Connect to localhost mongodb from python script started by torify

Tags: python, mongodb, dns, tor

When I'm trying to connect to the mongodb from my python script I see this warning many times and error finally:

`[Dec 13 11:58:56] WARNING torsocks[8133]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect.c:177)`

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

I use `torify` command for starting my command - `torify python myscript.py`. Without `torify` it works.

What I'm doing wrong? The same situation is on another machines to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this case. I have to create a Hidden Service first. To do that I have to add this lines to my tor config file (/etc/tor/torrc):

```
HiddenServiceDir /tmp/tormongo
HiddenServicePort 27017 127.0.0.1:27017
```

After that I need to restart my tor service. If everything was done right the folder has to appear in `/tmp`. In this folder will be the new file `hostname` with the string like `sgwqrpepus3lwcke.onion`. This is the host what I can use instead of `localhost` in mongodb connection settings.

Or I can add a new ENV variable for this setting and set it every script start by using command like that:

```
export DB_HOST=$(cat /tmp/tormongo/hostname) && torify python /var/www/myproject/myscript.py
```